# How do I do a search in the google lens window from the url?

Tags: python, html, url

search from url

if a normal search can be done like this

[www.google.com/search?q=search_here](http://www.google.com/search?q=search_here)

how do i search here !?
search from url with picture url in google lens

[image: search from url with picture url in google lens]

enable search with image url, from the url
in the same place that appears in the image

[image: search from url with picture url]

help me pls... TnT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

Use this link to search image with Google Lens:

```
https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=<image_url>
```

example: https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link: "https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://www.example.com/image.jpg"

and replace the URL at the end with your image URL

Comment: the solution does not give expected results
www.google.com/searchbyimage?q=https://www.example.com/my_image.png
redirects a 
https://www.google.com/imghp?sbi=1

Comment: @AliceNew try changing the full “example.com” url at the end to an actual image url, make sure it ends in “.jpg” or any other proper image extention that Google normally accepts. as long as it’s a real image, it will work. for example, this would search for an image of stack overflow: “ https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url= https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/product/teams/screens/illo-home-search.png”

Comment: the search is done by image thanks, but my real goal is to try a search through the google lens window for through the url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).